# Convert xml file to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe

I am new to using pandas with xml data and I can't figure out how to convert an xml file to pandas dataframe using the standard read_xml function. I tried the following code, but it is not picking up the data fields

```
import pandas as pd

xml='''
<TimeSeries xmlns="http://www.wldelft.nl/fews/PI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.wldelft.nl/fews/PI http://fews.wldelft.nl/schemas/version1.0/pi-schemas/pi_timeseries.xsd" version="1.26" xmlns:fs="http://www.wldelft.nl/fews/fs">
    <timeZone>1.0</timeZone>
    <series>
        <header>
            <type>instantaneous</type>
            <moduleInstanceId>pr.pompvolumes</moduleInstanceId>
            <locationId>SL000246</locationId>
            <parameterId>Q.B.d</parameterId>
            <timeStep unit="second" multiplier="86400"/>
            <startDate date="2018-01-01" time="00:00:00"/>
            <endDate date="2022-01-01" time="00:00:00"/>
            <missVal>NaN</missVal>
            <stationName>Putten vijzel</stationName>
            <lat>52.263570497449855</lat>
            <lon>5.495717667656339</lon>
            <x>162408.0</x>
            <y>475066.0</y>
            <units>m3/s</units>
        </header>
        <event date="2018-01-01" time="00:00:00" value="1.262" flag="0"/>
        <event date="2018-01-02" time="00:00:00" value="1.456" flag="0"/>
        <event date="2018-01-03" time="00:00:00" value="0.845" flag="0"/>
        <event date="2018-01-04" time="00:00:00" value="1.507" flag="0"/>
        <event date="2018-01-05" time="00:00:00" value="1.083" flag="0"/>
        <event date="2018-01-06" time="00:00:00" value="0.516" flag="0"/>
        </series>
</TimeSeries>
'''

df = pd.read_xml(xml)
```

The resulting dataframe should have a format such as:

```
data = [['2018-01-01', 1.262, 0], ['2018-01-02', 1.456, 0], ['2018-01-03', 0.845, 0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['event date', 'value', 'flag' ])
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your XML contains a default namespace which you must acknowledge or nothing will be parsed.

Answer (score 3):

- Use [`pd.read_xml`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html) with a `dict` assigned to the `namespaces` parameter, where the key is a "temporary namespace prefix" (e.g. `doc`), and the value references the namespace denoted as `xmlns` (so: `http://www.wldelft.nl/fews/PI`).
- This dict is then used to find the correct `xpath`. Here: `'doc:series/doc:event'`.

```
df = pd.read_xml(xml, xpath='doc:series/doc:event', 
                 namespaces={'doc':'http://www.wldelft.nl/fews/PI'})

print(df)

         date      time  value  flag
0  2018-01-01  00:00:00  1.262     0
1  2018-01-02  00:00:00  1.456     0
2  2018-01-03  00:00:00  0.845     0
3  2018-01-04  00:00:00  1.507     0
4  2018-01-05  00:00:00  1.083     0
5  2018-01-06  00:00:00  0.516     0

# drop `time`
df.drop('time', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: You can specify required column **names** as list in kwargs.

Comment: @Vovin: how do you do this? I mean, I know that you can pass names for the columns, but this will just rename the returned columns in order and then cut off the rest. E.g. in this case, if we do not pass anything, we get `['date','time','value','flag']`. If you pass `names=['date','value']`, this will return the *values* from `['date','time']`, but merely *renamed*: `['date','value']`.

Comment: I am sorry. I was inattentive, you are right.

Comment: @Vovin: no worries, would be a nice feature, surely!